# Is possible to use hibernate's @GeneratedValue manually?

Tags: hibernate

For high level demands I had to change type of an @Id column from Long to String, where value can be choose or just increase, defined by during software installation.

So I have this today:

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(
        schema = "SIS",
        name = "cadvei001_gen",
        table = "ADMSIS000",
        pkColumnName = "TABELA",
        pkColumnValue = "CADVEI001",
        valueColumnName = "VALOR",
        allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "cadvei001_gen")
@Column(name = "VEI001_CODIGO", length = 20, unique = true)
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

of course, this doesn't work. My question is: Is possible to use Hibernate's functions to get values from `tableGerenator` and update it directly, without this annotation, something like:

```
 Hibernate.getSequence("CADVEI001");
 Hibernate.updateSequence("CADVEI001");
```

Thank you everyone!